# Angular JS - How can I sum json array value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

How can I sum the `totalItem` quantity in my JSON array data?

```
[{"group": "B", "totalItem": 1},
{"group": "A", "totalItem": 1},
{"group": "C", "totalItem": 2},
{"group": "B", "totalItem": 3},
{"group": "A", "totalItem": 6},
{"group": "C", "totalItem": 2},]
```

Given above example how can I sum all `totalItem` that has the same group in angular?

Comment: Did you google it. Sorry to be rude but this is very common problem.

Comment: Angular has nothing to do ith this. It's just plain JavaScript/logic. Learn about loops and array operations. And try something.

Answer (score 1):

simple as "Good day"

```js
let counters = myArray.reduce((p,n) => {
  if(p[n.group]) { p[n.group] += n.totalItem; }
  else { p[n.group] = n.totalItem; }
  return p;
}, []);
```

This is a common groupBy in Javascript. First, you have the `reduce` function on an array : it goes through the array and do anything you want.

The first parameter is a function that will do what you ask, and the second parameter is the start value.

So here, you start with an empty array `[]`.

Then, you iterate over your items. I have named 2 variables, `p` for previous (value that will be returned at the end), and `n` for next (current object of the array).

The condition says :

> If the group in the array exists, then add the totalItem to it. If not, then create it with the value of totalItem.

At the end, you have an associative array containing all of your groups !

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: This is a Javascript groupBy function. It's pretty common, I don't think there is a need for an explanation. But I will put it, since you asked.

Comment: Why use [] as initial value? Surely you meant {}. Also, a curly brace is missing.

Comment: No, I meant `[]`. this is an associative array of values, as described in the explanation. But sure, you can use `{}`, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method you can understand the process through.

```
var totals = {};   //This object will have the sums of each group

//Go through your array
myArray.forEach(function(item){   

    if (typeof totals[item.group] === 'undefined')     
        totals[item.group] = item.totalItem            //Create a new group item in the result object
    else                                               
        totals[item.group] += item.totalItem;          //Item is there - so aggregate the value

})
```